# UIButton visible background

Tags: swift, uibutton, calayer, uibackgroundcolor

Can't find any useful information about custom view field on UIButton
I need to create a subclass of UIButton with big button frame and small visible part of it
Also I need to animate background on button tap so I need to set button background as a backgroundImage

Here is my code:

```
public final class BigSmallButton: UIButton {
...

public override var buttonType: UIButton.ButtonType {
    return .custom
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                       attribute: .height,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: nil,
                       attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                       multiplier: 1.0,
                       constant: 44).isActive = true

    let imageSize = CGSize(width: 24, height: 24)
    let backgroundImage = UIImage.image(with: Constants.buttonBackgroundColor, size: imageSize)
    setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal)

    layer.cornerRadius = Constants.buttonIconSize.height / 2.0
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: imageSize.height)
}
```

And then add to NavigationController

```
let bigSmallButton = BigSmallButton(frame: .zero)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: bigSmallButton)
```

It works but my button height becomes equal to **24.0** not **44.0**

I need answer about is it possible to make such button?

And if it's possible then what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: What does "big frame but small visible part" even mean? What's the real problem here? I'm guessing that what you _really_ want is to make the bar button item tappable outside its visible region, is that it? So you want to inset the button image relative to the actual bounds of the bar button item? If so, there's a much simpler and correct way that doesn't involve subclassing UIButton.

Comment: Yes you are right ))
I need bar button item tappable outside it's visible region
Visible region in design == 24 pt but by guidelines I must make button height at least 44 pt. Can't find out how to do that

Comment: About subclass of UIButton I think it’s necessary 'cause I want to make reusable UI element behaving the same way on different screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I found is overriding button function `point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?)`

Something like this:

```
let hitFrame: CGRect

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        hitFrame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY - 10.0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height + 10.0)
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return hitFrame.contains(point)
    }
```